# Find contour of the set of points in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, contour, mser

I try to find objects on image by MSER-detection from OpenCV. But function `cvExtractMSER` return not contours, but set of points (`CvSeq`), that create figure:

```
(1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), ...
```

[image: Area created by set of points]

But I needs only points of contour:

```
(1, 4), (8, 4), (8, 1), (4, 1)
```

[image: Highlight needed contour points]

**How I can find this contour?**

I think, that simplest (but not fastest) way is:

- draw b/w image with all points (how? point-by-point?)
- use `findContours` for find contours on new image

Comment: It's been 2 years, so you might already have the solution to your question. I'm running into the same problem. Thus I think the documentation of OpenCV that describes MSER to return the "contours" is not correct:

"//runs the extractor on the specified image; returns the MSERs,
// each encoded as a contour (vector<Point>, see findContours)
// the optional mask marks the area where MSERs are searched for (...)"

Answer (score 1):

One of the options in findContours() is to pass a parameter that will remove all points except end points on a straight horizontal, vertical, or diagonal line. If you create an image and draw the points you've listed, then findContours() can do the rest of the work for you.

> CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE compresses horizontal, vertical, and diagonal segments and leaves only their end points. For example, an up-right rectangular contour is encoded with 4 points.

http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours

Comment: "create an image and draw the points you've listed, then findContours() can do the rest of the work"
Yes, I think, it's simplest way (I wrote it in bottom of post). But I don't know fast way of drawing sequence of points on image. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The most generalized way to get those points for any shape would be to use a convex hull on the contours. ([Hull Tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1d/tutorial_hull.html))

But, in case you are only looking for the 4 extreme points in each direction, you can do that simply treating the contours like a NumPy array (which they are):

if `c` is a contour:

```py
extLeft = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
extRight = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
extTop = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
extBot = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
```

More on this can be found here: [pyimagesearch.com "Finding Extreme Points in Contours with OpenCV"](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/11/finding-extreme-points-in-contours-with-opencv/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you are looking for the corners of the detected object.

You can iterate through your list of countours and write a simple **logic to detect the 4 corners** by doing simple coordinates comparisons.

Comment: I think that is not good answer. What if he has different shape which needs more corners to make contour? Simple logic become not simple to write.

Comment: Perhaps karlphillip probably meant to say convex hull?